# Left click doesn't work in edit mode in saved files

Tags: selection-tools

When I open a previously saved file (.blend) I have a different type of selection tools (picture 2) in edit mode and I can't use left click. How can get the standart selection tools? I'm starting to learn blender and I can't find this information anywhere...

[image: these are the tools when I open edit mode in a new file]

[image: these selection tools I have when I open edit mode in a saved file I worked on before]

Comment: Hello and welcome :). It looks like some older Blender version with right click selection. Make sure you open .blend files with Blender 2.81.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by installing the newest version of Blender (2.81). Thanks for help :)